# Why my binding does not work?

Tags: silverlight

Have class behine the xaml that contain the propertie 'Int32 Count'

I want to bind some TextBlock to the 'Count' value - that the TextBlock.Text will have the value of the 'Count'.

So i wrote in the xaml :

```
 <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Path=Count }" />
```

And in the code behind the xaml i add to the constructor:

```
  DataContext = this;
```

But each change of the 'Count' does not change the text of the TextBlock.

The code of 'Count'

```
Int32 count;
public Int32 Count
{
      get
      {
           return count;
      }

      set
      {
           count = value;
      }

}
```

Comment: what is the code of the Count property ? And are you trying to bind the window to itself ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

place the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to your class:

```
public class MainPage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

}
```

then implement:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
```

what this does if provide the mechanism for notifying the view that something has changed in your datacontext and you do it like this:

```
public Int32 Count
{
      get
      {
           return count;
      }

      set
      {
           count = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Count"); //This invokes the change
      }

}
```

But of course, i recommend that you separate design and code using the MVVM pattern. This way, you can implement the propertychanged to a ViewModelBase class, then inherit that for each of your ViewModels.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure your  DataContext implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Then you have to fire the property change events properly.